# How to count the number of shakes detected using javascript

Tags: javascript

http://www.ivangabriele.com/cordova-detecting-shaking/

I'm learning to write a shake function in javascript. But I don't know how to detect and count the number of shakes done by the user, can anyone give me a hand?

```
    shake.startWatch(onShake);

    function onShake()
    {
      alert('Shook');
    }

    // Stop watching for shaking event
    shake.stopWatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could count the shakes.

```
shake.startWatch(onShake);
var count = 0;
function onShake()
{
  alert('Shook');
  count++ //increases count by 1 each time the function is called.
}

// Stop watching for shaking event
shake.stopWatch();
```